# Why does `ObjectSpace._id2ref` give different outputs on Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.0

Why does `ObjectSpace._id2ref` give different outputs on Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 2.0?

**Ruby 1.9.3p392 i386-mingw32**

```
class Foo ; end

Foo.object_id                     #=> 17569464
ObjectSpace._id2ref(17569464)     #=> Foo

Foo.new.singleton_class.object_id #=> 17075124
ObjectSpace._id2ref(17075124)     #=> "\x00"
```

**Ruby 2.0.0p0 i386-mingw32**

```
class Foo ; end

Foo.object_id                     #=> 17197176
ObjectSpace._id2ref(17197176)     #=> Foo

Foo.new.singleton_class.object_id #=> 19181436
ObjectSpace._id2ref(19181436)     #=> RangeError: 0x124af7c is recycled object

Foo.new.singleton_class.object_id #=> 17454324
ObjectSpace._id2ref(17454324)     #=> RangeError: 0x10a54f4 is not id value

Foo.new.singleton_class.object_id #=> 17139816
ObjectSpace._id2ref(17139816)     #=> "c"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because in `2.0` the garbage collector was defter.

```
# RangeError: 0x124af7c is recycled object
```

states for *the object was already GC’ed*.

**UPD:** We can approach the requested behaviour with [`Mutex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Mutex.html):

```
2.0.0 (main):0 > Mutex.new.synchronize {
2.0.0 (main):0 *   class Foo ; end
2.0.0 (main):0 *   id = Foo.new.singleton_class.object_id
2.0.0 (main):0 *   puts id
2.0.0 (main):0 *   puts ObjectSpace._id2ref(id)
2.0.0 (main):0 * }  
# 23172260
# <Class:#<Foo:0x00000002c32970>>
```

Comment: please see my `EDIT`. With Ruby2.0 that output changes

Comment: You are trying to print out the piece of memory heap which is already purged. Everything may be printed, there is no contract on such a doing. Try to embrace calls to `new` and `_id2ref` into mutex at least.

Comment: your suggestion is valuable to me, so what you are suggesting,could you put that into your answer?

Comment: but why GC is not called in every cases?

Comment: GC is running in the separate thread. If there is a mutex, no other thread may touch the objects concurrently. If there is no one, the other thread may (or may not) gain an access to the objects. GC may (or may not) keep pace with cleaning up the memory.